# Iterating over a list and subtracting values

Tags: python

I have a list of numbers

```
((100),(99),(97),(96),(3),(2))
```

If the second number is within 2 of the number before it I would like to take 2 from that number and all the numbers after it in the list unless the last number becomes negative, for example

```
First iteration, substrate 2 from 97 and lower
((100), (97), (95), (94,),(1),(0))

Second iteration, substrate 2 from 94 and lower
((100), (97), (95), (92), (0),(0))
```

Comment: And your question is?  What have you tried?

Comment: It's fairly easy to solve this in O(n), but you have specifically described an O(n**2) implementation

Comment: Shouldn't the second iteration be `(100, 97, 93, 92, 0, 0)`?

Answer (score 0):

here is an answer using a recursive function `shift`, and helper function `subtract2`:

```
def subtract2(p, i):
    while i < len(p):
        p[i] = p[i] - 2 if p[i] - 2 >= 0 else p[i]
        i += 1

def shift(p, i):
    # base case
    if i >= len(p) - 1:
        return
    elif p[i] - 2 <= p[i+1]:
        subtract2(p, i+1)
    # recurse
    return shift(p, i+1)
```

Hope this helps